# MongoDB extra Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have a db called index having only one collection named student.

When I fire query `db.students.find({}).count()`

It shows 1000000 docs in it.

But when I used db.stats() It shows result like:-

```
{
        "db" : "index",
        "collections" : 3,
        "objects" : 1000004,
        "avgObjSize" : 59.95997216011136,
        "dataSize" : 59960212,
        "storageSize" : 87420928,
        "numExtents" : 14,
        "indexes" : 1,
        "indexSize" : 32458720,
        "fileSize" : 520093696,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

1. 3 collections how ?
2. No of object 1000004 which is 4 extra from expected ?

And finally i did `db.getCollectionNames()`
it shows `[ "student", "system.indexes" ]`

What is `system.indexes` ?

Please anybody elaborate on it?

I am new to the world of mongo.

Comment: `system.indexes` is metadata: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/

Comment: @w0lf great but one more doubt is if I did db.getCollectionNames() it shows only 2 collections so why 3 in stats()

Comment: Right. I just realized I have a db in which `show collections` shows 4 items, but `db.stats()` shows a count of 5. Interested to see what is the answer :)

Comment: yup lets wait for some genius person.

Comment: @squiroid: Albeit not being a genius, I hope you will find my answer helpful. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The mysterious 2 collections

There are two collections created when a user stores data in a database for the first time or a database is created explicitly.

The first one, [`system.indexes`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/#<database>.system.indexes) holds the information about the indices defined in the various collections of the database. You can even access it using

```
db.system.indexes.find()
```

The hidden one, [`system.namespaces`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/#<database>.system.namespaces) holds some metadata about the database, actually the name of all existing entities from the point of view of the database management.

Although it is not shown, you can still access it:

```
db.system.namespaces.find()
```

**Warning**: Don't fiddle with either of them. Your database may well become unusable. You have been warned!

There can be even more than those two. Read [*System Collections* in the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/#system-collections) for details.

#### The mysterious 4 objects

Actually, If you have tried to access the system databases as shown above, this one becomes very easy. In a database called `foobardb` with a collection `foo` and the default index on `_id`, querying `system.indexes` will give a result like this (prettified):

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "foobardb.foo"
}
```

Note that this is a single document. The prettified output of the second query looks like this:

```
{ "name" : "foobardb.foo" }
{ "name" : "foobardb.system.indexes" }
{ "name" : "foobardb.foo.$_id_" }
```

Here, we have three documents. So we have 4 additional documents inside the metadata.

Comment: Nice answer. Just want to add that these collections are an implementation detail and, for example, don't exist in the same way in WiredTiger. Not only should you not alter them, you shouldn't use them at all.

Comment: @wdberkeley: Thank you, but the truth is that all rep should go to Adam and MongoU. ;)